# How to Remove Bluetooth Manager in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, bluetooth, services

I wanna remove bluetooth manager and its daemon from Xubuntu because my computer doesn't have bluetooth device.  How should I do?

Note : I've searched questions https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Remove+Bluetooth but I find nothing. Wish I don't create duplicate question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following shell command will remove bluetooth and all its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge "bluez*"
```

If this prompts you to remove the `xubuntu-desktop` meta-package, do not be alarmed. This is acceptable.

If installed, also remove the `obex-data-server` and the `libopenobex` package. The `libbluetooth*` package(s) must remain since too many stuff depends on it.

Afterwards, you should also run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you. It tries to remove gnome-user-share. Please your suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest: let it remove it. There may be better sharing tools around that do not depend on bluetooth.

Comment: What is it? Could you give me choises?

Comment: The following packages will be REMOVED:
`blueman* bluez*...   ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop*`
 –  Ubuntu mate core?!? – does not sound like a good idea to me!